# Extracting font data with CGPDFScanner

Tags: ios, pdf, cgpdf

I'm using `CGPDFScanner`to scan PDF. When the scanner encounters something like:

```
BT
/F13 12 Tf 288 720 Td (ABC) Tj
ET
```

I use operator callbacks to extract the `Tf`, `Td` and `Tj` data. How do I extract `/F13`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *name*, a special form of string, usually used as dictionary keys. You can pop it with `CGPDFScannerPopName`. The information about the actual font is contained in the page's `Resources` dictionary, which contains a `Font` dictionary.

Comment: So the font name that's popped in the `Tf` callback is a key to a value in the font dictionary (itself a value in the page resource dictionary)?

Comment: Yes. Be sure to read the [PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for details. Fonts in PDF are a pretty complex topic.